# Howto modify Vue Data from vanilla JS event listener?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I've got a barcode scanner app based on a simple keyboard logger and some vue data I'd like to address in a proper way. Please have a look at the following simplified (working) sample.
Is there a better way to access the `packageA` array than doing a `var obj = this;` to address my vue instance instead of document?

```
export default {
  name: "xxx",
  data() {
    return {
      packageA: []
    };
  },
  created: function () {
     var obj = this;
     document.addEventListener('keyup', function (e) {
       obj.packageA.push(e.key)
     });
  }
}
```

What would be a proper way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use arrow function :

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#demo",
  data() {
    return {
      packageA: []
    };
  },
  created() {
    document.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
      this.packageA.push(e.key)
    });
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  {{ packageA }}
</div>
```

Comment: ah, ok - the reason for that:   
"Unlike regular functions, *arrow* functions don’t have their own this or arguments binding. Instead, those identifiers are resolved in the lexical scope like any other variable."